# Can't find react-uwp namespace when compiling typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, uwp

I used the create-react-app tool along with the typescript scripts to generate a default react project using typescript.  Then I tried to add react-uwp using npm (--save).  It installed fine and it's in my node_modules folder.  I modified my tsconfig.json as the 'getting started' page for react-uwp indicates. 
(Here: https://www.react-uwp.com/Get-Started)

There are two options:

1. Add the react-uwp module folder to 'typeRoots'
2. Add 'index.d.ts' from the react-uwp folder to the 'include' section

I've tried both (not at the same time) and in both cases, the typescript compiler chokes:

`error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'ReactUWP'.`

Any ideas?  The typings are in the actual module folder, not a separate package.  This is my current tsconfig.json without either of those two changes:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"outDir": "build/dist",
"module": "esnext",
"target": "es5",
"lib": ["es6", "dom"],
"sourceMap": true,
"allowJs": true,
"jsx": "react",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"rootDir": "src",
"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
"noImplicitReturns": true,
"noImplicitThis": true,
"noImplicitAny": true,
"strictNullChecks": true,
"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
"noUnusedLocals": true
// "typeRoots": [
//   "./node_modules/@types",
//   "./node_modules/react-uwp"
// ]
},
// "include": [
//   "./node_modules/react-uwp/index.d.ts"
// ],
"exclude": [
  "node_modules",
  "build",
  "scripts",
  "acceptance-tests",
  "webpack",
  "jest",
  "src/setupTests.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: As a temporary workaround, I'm using a triple-slash directive at the top of the file:  /// <reference path="../node_modules/react-uwp/index.d.ts" />

Comment: I also faced the same error.